# Recursive query for MySql - get all subtree

Tags: mysql, recursion, view, recursive-query

Lets assume that there is a factory that produces products. the factory have catalog of a products, therefore `tbl_catalog` will be.

```
+----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| catalog_number | catalog_name | details                                       |
+----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|              1 | LaptopX      | Full assembled laptop - X                     |
|              2 | Top Half     | Where the screen & webcam are                 |
|              3 | Bottom Half  | Where mothereboard, and rest of the parts are |
|              4 | WebCam       | WebCam for laptopX                            |
|              5 | LcdX         | Lcd screen for laptopX                        |
|              6 | Keyboard     | set of keys                                   |
|              7 | SSD          | Place to store data                           |
|              8 | Touchpad     | If there is no mouse connected                |
|              9 | DVD          | to play music and watch movies                |
|             10 | Lazer Beam   | a must have for our DVD                       |
|             11 | EngineX      | EngineX will spin our DVD with no problem     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Products composed of other products in the catalog - represented as tree, for our sample, `tbl_catalog_tree` will be:

```
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |        2 |
|         1 |        3 |
|         2 |        4 |
|         2 |        5 |
|         3 |        6 |
|         3 |        7 |
|         3 |        8 |
|         3 |        9 |
|         9 |       10 |
|         9 |       11 |
+-----------+----------+
```

That's for the catalog. now lets assemble some products. we need another table - `assembly`:

```
+------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| id   | catalog_number | assembled_by | qc_by |
+------+----------------+--------------+-------+
|  100 |             11 | Joe          | Dan   |
|  101 |             11 | Joe          | Dan   |
|  102 |             11 | Joe          | Dan   |
|  200 |             10 | Joe          | Dan   |
|  201 |             10 | Joe          | Dan   |
|  201 |             10 | Joe          | Dan   |
|  300 |              9 | Mike         | Dan   |
|  301 |              9 | Mike         | Dan   |
|  302 |              9 | Mike         | Dan   |
+------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

but we still don't know what is the connection between the DVD's sub parts so we need `tbl_assembly_tree`:

```
+-----------+----------------------+----------+
| parent_id | child_catalog_number | child_id |
+-----------+----------------------+----------+
|       302 |                   11 | 100      |
|       302 |                   10 | 200      |
|       301 |                   11 | 101      |
|       301 |                   10 | 201      |
|       300 |                   11 | 102      |
|       300 |                   10 | 202      |
+-----------+----------------------+----------+
```

since sub trees can be part of different catalogs (like this DVD that can mee part of laptopX and a future laptopY) we need to know what is the child catalog number for the specific assembly (and not count on the catalog tree structur).

My question is:
How to query so I get a product and all it's sub tree products?
If I want to query the DB about all the assmbled Items of a catalog number and for each assembly to know who build and who qc all it's sub parts recursively,in the above example, If Ill query for DVD I want the answer to be something like:

```
+----+---------+----------+---------+--------+------------+----------+--------+-------+
| id | cat_num | cat_name | assy_by | sub_id |sub_cat_num | sub_name | ass_by | qc_by |
+----+---------+----------+---------+--------+------------+----------+--------+-------+
| 300|     9   |   DVD    |  Mike   |   102  |  11        | EngineX  |  Joe   | Dan   |
| 300|     9   |   DVD    |  Mike   |   202  |  10        | Lazer B  |  Joe   | Dan   |
| 301|     9   |   DVD    |  Mike   |   101  |  11        | EngineX  |  Joe   | Dan   |
| 301|     9   |   DVD    |  Mike   |   201  |  10        | Lazer B  |  Joe   | Dan   |
| 302|     9   |   DVD    |  Mike   |   100  |  11        | EngineX  |  Joe   | Dan   |
| 302|     9   |   DVD    |  Mike   |   200  |  10        | Lazer B  |  Joe   | Dan   |
+----+---------+----------+---------+--------+------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Of course, if all the catalog was one level only I wouldn't put this question here, but I need this to be recursive, so I can see all the subtrees of assemblies for a catalog number I select.

I've build an [sqlfiddle for the above example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de739) and hope that someone can help me on this

Comment: This will be very hard in MySQL as it does not support recursive queries and you can't write functions returning results. If you are stuck with MySQL you probably should use a different data model.

Answer (score 0):

The trick which came in mind is to join the same table several times.

This will give you the result you stated in your question:

```
SELECT
    d.parent_id as id,
    a.catalog_number,
    a.catalog_name,
    e.assembled_by,
    d.child_id as sub_id,
    b.child_id as sub_cat_num,
    c.catalog_name as sub_name,
    f.assembled_by as sub_assemly_by,
    e.qc_by

FROM
    catalog as a, catalog_tree as b, 
    catalog as c, assembly_tree as d, 
    assembly as e , assembly as f

WHERE 
    a.catalog_name = 'DVD'
    and a.catalog_number = b.parent_id
    and b.child_id = c.catalog_number
    and b.child_id = d.child_catalog_number
    and d.parent_id = e.id
    and d.child_id = f.id
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Hi Benny, Thanks for your response, you answer is correct only if the tree height is X (in your case - x=2) I want a way to do that dynamiclly so if one will want to see all teh subtree of laptopX he will see all the parts on the right side of the table - including the DVD's subparts. your approch does not cover the general case.